# seaborn - how to graph a list of list of ints with labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I currently have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
     name  class           scores
1     Bob  history     [13, 14, 11]
2   Chuck  math        [12,  7,  8]
3   Daren  history     [26, 14,  9]
4   Elisa  english     [ 8, 14, 10]
5   Aaron  history     [12, 13, 23]
6     Tom  math        [ 7,  7, 28]
7     Dan  history     [13,  2, 13]
8    Fred  english     [ 4,  1,  2]
```

And I would like to graph this dataframe with the x-axis being `scores`, the y-axis being the count of `scores`, and the label (or hue) to be determined by `class`. Ultimately, it would look similar to this plot (code from https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html)

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.histplot(penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", hue="species", element="step")
```

[image: stacked histplot with label]

where count would be the count of `scores`, flipper_length_mm would be the value of each score, and species would be `class`.

I have been trying all sorts of method with zippings and list flattenings but I can't seem to get anything to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode` scores column so that you can count each different element, and don't forget to set `ignore_index=True`:

```
df2 = df.explode('scores', ignore_index=True)
sns.histplot(df2, x="scores", hue="class", element='step')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you! By any chance, is there some other way to achieve the same histplot output without having to compute all the additional rows that get generated?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant, but  `explode` seems one of the fastest and most succinct solutions I could think of.